# Sequence in $l^2$ that does not converge (but it should?)

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $l^2$ be the space of all real sequences  $x = (x_1,x_2, x_3,\;...)$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2$ converges. It can be easily verified that map
$$\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n$$
defines an inner product on $l^2$ and that $x\to ||x||=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ defines norm on $l^2$, therefore one can speak about Cauchy's sequences. I am aware of the fact that if the sequence $\{x^j\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$, $x^j\in l^2$ , converges, it must be Cauchy's. Clearly, the seqence 
$$x^1 =(1,0,0,0\;...)\\ x^2 = (0,1,0,0,\;...)\\x^3 = (0,0,1,0, \; ...)\\ \vdots$$
is not Cauchy's, since $||x^j-x^k||=\sqrt{2}$ for all $j\neq k$. As consequence, it cannot be convergent. On the other hand, we can notice that 
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \forall j\in \mathbb{N}. n>j \Rightarrow x^j_n = 0\text{,}$$
so - intuitively - *kind of limit* exists and equals to $x = (0,0,0,\;...)$. My question is:

> Is there any *natural* topology (or metric) for which the upper sequence really converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this converges to the zero sequence in the weak topology. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#The_weak_and_strong_topologies).